# spresenseのSPIを使用してSDカードにwavファイルを記録したい

Tags: spresense

arduino IDEで開発しています。
spresenseのSPIラインを使用してSDカードにwavファイルを記録したいです。
SDHCIライブラリなどを使用して、SPIラインを指定することはできるでしょうか。

Comment: Audio ライブラリを使用する場合、writeWavHeaderやreadFramesなどFile オブジェクトに対して処理されるので、File オブジェクトをSPIで接続されたsdカードに紐付けたいです。

Comment: SDHCIライブラリはSPIをインターフェースとして指定する機能はありません。なので、昔メインボードだけでSDカードを使いたいと思い、SPI5用のSDカードライブラリを作ったことがあります。(https://github.com/YoshinoTaro/SPISD-for-SpresenseMainboard)　ただ、かなり書き込み速度は遅いです。録音は書き込み速度が要求されるので、Arduinoなどで使われているSPIのSDカードライブラリが使えても、録音はまともにできないように思います。（FIFOが溢れてすぐ止まるのではないかと…）

Comment: 記事やライブラリを参考にさせて頂き、SPI5でMP3の録音はできたのですが、WAV録音はご指摘の通りうまく動きませんでした。SDHCIよりも消費電力を押さえてWAV録音（モノラル、48kHz、16nit）をする方法を検討しています。

Comment: 拡張ボードのSPI4でも確認しましたが、WAVはSPI5と同様に開始早々止まってしまいました。また、MP3録音での消費電力を比較したところ、SDHCIよりSPIの方が悪い結果だったので、目的に合わない方法ということが分かりました。